# Determine which compiler built my LAPACK

Tags: numpy, fortran, lapack, gfortran, g77

I want to install the newest version of `numpy` (a numerical library for Python), and the version (v1.6.1) is not yet in the [Ubuntu Oneiric repositories](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/python-numpy). When I went ahead to manually install it, I read in the [INSTALL](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/INSTALL.txt) file that `numpy` needs to be built with the same compiler that built `LAPACK` (a fortran lib used by `numpy`). Unfortunately, I don't know which compiler that is. I didn't install `LAPACK` myself - `apt-get` did, back when I installed an older `numpy` (v1.5.1) using `apt`. If I had to guess, I'd say `gfortran`, but I'd rather not mess this up.

How do I figure out which compiler built my current installation of `LAPACK`? Is there any easy way - perhaps running some fortran code that uses it and examining the output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the same `INSTALL` file you referenced...

```
How to check the ABI of blas/lapack/atlas
-----------------------------------------

One relatively simple and reliable way to check for the compiler used to build
a library is to use ldd on the library. If libg2c.so is a dependency, this
means that g77 has been used. If libgfortran.so is a a dependency, gfortran has
been used. If both are dependencies, this means both have been used, which is
almost always a very bad idea.
```

If I had to guess, I would probably guess gfortran also as the only two free fortran compilers that I know of are g77 and gfortran and g77 development is pretty much dead as far as I know ... Another thing to check is g77 (by default) appended two underscores to symbols whereas gfortran (by default) only appends one.  This is probably the thing that is most important for numpy to know ... although there may be other subtle differences (if numpy is doing some dirty hacking to get at information stored in a common block for instance).

Comment: Thanks! Just what I need. To use `ldd` on `lapack`, I `cd`'d to `/usr/lib/` and executed `$ ldd liblapack.*` (my lapack file looks like `liblapack.so.3gf`). My [results](http://pastebin.com/pgSHha9R) point to `gfortran`. Thanks again for finding this and sharing.

Comment: @caravaggisto  No problem -- I'm glad to help.  If this worked for you, feel free to accept this answer ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work )

Answer (score 2):

I know of no easy way, though you may find `readelf -a /usr/lib/$SHARED_OBJECT` illuminating, where `$SHARED_OBJECT` is something like `/usr/lib/atlas-base/liblapack_atlas.so.3gf.0` (you'll have to look in your `/usr/lib` to see what your exact filename is).

However, there is another, quite different way to get information, since you are using Ubuntu, a flavor of Debian.

1. Find out which to binary package $BINARY_PKG your Lapack shared object belongs by `dpkg -l | grep -E '(lapack|atlas)` and/or `dpkg -S $SHARED_OBJECT`.
2. Find out from which source package $SOURCE_PKG the binary package $BINARY_PKG was built by `dpkg -s $BINARY_PACKAGE`.  In the output, look for the `Source:` line.
3. Change into some temporary working directory.
4. Issue `apt-get source $SOURCE_PKG`.  (Alternately, `apt-get source $BINARY_PKG` has the same effect.)
5. Issue `ls` and notice the Lapack source directory.
6. Change into the Lapack source directory.
7. Examine the file `debian/control`, paying special attention to the relevant `Build-Depends:` line.  This will tell what was necessary to build the package.
8. Issue `dpkg -s build-essential`, which will give you additional information about compilers available to build every package in your distribution (you may have to install the `build-essential` package, first).

All this is of course a lot of work, and none of it is in the nature of a simple formula that just gives you the answer you seek; but it does give you places to look for the answer.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! `readelf` [worked great](http://pastebin.com/C4YggTfX), and confirmed the results from `ldd`. The other steps look a bit overkill for my needs, but thanks for sharing.